# how to find out which check in express validator is triggering the errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I'm creating a web app that has an admin user who is the only one who can create other users. I'm storing the admin user username and password in the `.env` file and using the `dotenv` package.
My problem is when I'm comparing the username and password to the env variables using a `custom` check (using `express-validator`)it always triggers the errors even though all my `console.log()` inside the custom validation do not show in the terminal.

Here is my `router`

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const { logAdmin} = require('../../controllers/admin');
const { validateAdminLogIn } = require('../../utils/adminValidation');

// log admin in
router.post('/login', validateAdminLogIn, logAdmin);
```

and my `adminValidation`

```js
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

exports.validateAdminLogIn = [
  check('username').custom((value) => {
    if (value !== process.env.ADMIN_USER) {
      console.log('no user match') // this doesn't run
      return Promise.reject('wrong username or password');
    }
  }),
  check('password').custom((value) => {
    if (value !== process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
      console.log("passwords don't match") // this never runs
      return Promise.reject('wrong username or password');
    }
  }),
  (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      console.log('there are errors');
      console.log(errors);
      return res.status(401).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    console.log('finished validation with no errors'); // never get to here
    next();
  },
];
```

and my `controller` which I haven't done anything with yet

```js
exports.logAdmin = (req, res) => {
  // get username and password
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  // match to the admin credentials
  // create token and send it as a cookie using the admin token secret
};
```

and here is my request (rest client for vs code)

```json
### admin
post http://localhost:5000/api/auth/admin/login
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "password"
}
```

and here are the errors result

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 169
ETag: W/"a9-zEKcgYJMgQx5PLgkFguKIPyF/5Q"
Date: Fri, 23 Apr 2021 22:35:22 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "errors": [
    {
      "value": "admin",
      "msg": "Invalid value",
      "param": "username",
      "location": "body"
    },
    {
      "value": "password",
      "msg": "Invalid value",
      "param": "password",
      "location": "body"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks, A lot

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem as I don't have a promise to reject in the first place. and also I'm not returning anything from the custom validator function if it has no errors

so here is how I fixed it

```js
check('username')
    .custom((value) => {
      const username = process.env.ADMIN_USER;
      if (value !== username) throw new Error('wrong username or password');
      return true;
    })
    .withMessage('user name error'),
  check('password').custom((value) => {
    const password = process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD;
    if (value !== password) throw new Error('wrong username or password');
    return true;
  }),
  (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    console.log(errors);
    if (!errors.isEmpty())
      return res.status(401).json({ errors: errors.array() });

    console.log('finished validation with no errors');
    next();
  },
```